# Nifi expression language for loops over attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

Currently I am having around 15 attributes in my flowfile. Out of these 15, i only want a few (all the attributes that have a prefix 'error_' in it. These 'error_*' attributes can have 2 sets of values, eighter- 'valid' or some error code, say- '945'. Now i want to iterate though all the attributes with prefix - 'error_' and if its value is 'valid', do nothing and if its value is having some error code, append the error code to a string separated by ';'. So basically, if I have 5 error_ attributes:

```
error_field1: '123'
error_field2: 'Valid'
error_field3: '567'
error_field4: 'Valid'
error_field5: '45'
```

I want my output as - **'123;567;45'**.

Please help me as i am new to Nifi and i am not sure on how to work with such complex EL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to perform this.

1. `${anyMatchingAttribute('error_'):find('\\d+')}`

You can use the [`anyMatchingAttribute()`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#anymatchingattribute) function to evaluate a predicate against multiple attributes, and use the regular expression [`find()`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#find) method to check for the presence of digits. This will give you a boolean result, but won't enumerate & join all the values.

2. `${allMatchingAttributes('error_'):join(';'):replaceAll('Valid;', '')}`

If you don't need to recall and associate the error codes with the specific field where they were sourced, you can simply concatenate all of the attributes and then use a regular expression to *remove* the `Valid` values.